# dynamic memory allocation using vectors and bubble sort

Tags: c++, vector

I need help in adding the user to enter value that becomes array size and will sort array by bubble sort its sorting however I need user to enter the value and it becomes value of an array ie. allocation memory dynamically

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//function to swap values
//need to pass by reference to sort the original values and not just these copies
void Swap (int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void BubbleSort (std::vector<int> &array)
{
    std::cout<<"Elements in the array: "<<array.size()<<std::endl;

    //comparisons will be done n times
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        //compare elemet to the next element, and swap if condition is true
        for(int j = 0; j < array.size() - 1; j++)
        {   
            if (array[j] > array[j+1])
                Swap(&array[j], &array[j+1]);
        }
    }
}

//function to print the array
void PrintArray (std::vector<int> array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        std::cout<<array[i]<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Enter array to be sorted (-1 to end)\n";

    std::vector<int> array;
    int num = 0;
    while (num != -1)
    {
        std::cin>>num;
        if (num != -1)
            //add elements to the vector container
            array.push_back(num);
    }

    //sort the array
    BubbleSort(array);

    std::cout<<"Sorted array is as\n";
    PrintArray(array);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried `cin` using while however array doesn't print

Comment: Improve by using pass by reference `void PrintArray (std::vector<int>& array)` Remove extra colon at the end of main scope.

Comment: I tried your program and its working fine. can you elaborate your question what you want because. the question you had asked about array printing is working

Comment: @RohitSuthar i am trying to get the input from user to enter how many elements he wnats to add that becomes my  size of array for example if one enters 10 my arrasize[10] becomes 10 and alloacted by user not defined i.e memory is allocated dynamically and then it should stop at 10 and sorts the array hope that elobartes better

Comment: Simply get the input from the user into one variable and then dynaically allocate array size like this int *arr = new int[size] after then run a loop from 0 to your input size variable and take input numbers from user and store it in array thats all.

Comment: @RohitSuthar i am really new can you help me in code this one it will really helpful i tried doing that however could not get the desired result if thats ok with you

Comment: If you tried it then please show that code and explain in which way it did not work. Try to focues your question on what got you stuck. The whole sorting part seems unneeded for your question how to create an array via dynamic allocation. Even the reading of the input size does not need to be shown. The idea is to create a [mcve] of only the part you tried but did not achieve.

Comment: As side notes:

1. Bubble sort doesn't require the inner loop to go over the whole vector each time. You can stop at array.size() - i - 1.

2. You don't need to implement swap yourself, STL has already done it for you.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your version and show you, how you can get the number of elements to sort from the user and hot to dynamically allocate memory in your array.

You will simply use the `std::vector`s constructor to define a size. Looks then like: `std::vector<int> array(numberOfElements);`.

The whole adapted code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//function to swap values
//need to pass by reference to sort the original values and not just these copies
void Swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void BubbleSort(std::vector<int>& array)
{
    std::cout << "Elements in the array: " << array.size() << std::endl;

    //comparisons will be done n times
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        //compare elemet to the next element, and swap if condition is true
        for (size_t j = 0; j < array.size() - 1; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
                Swap(&array[j], &array[j + 1]);
        }
    }
}

//function to print the array
void PrintArray(std::vector<int> array)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the number of data to sort: ";  
    size_t numberOfElements{ 0 };                        
    std::cin >> numberOfElements;                        

    std::vector<int> array(numberOfElements);
    size_t counter{ 0 };

    std::cout << "\nEnter "<< numberOfElements << " data\n";

    int num = 0;
    while ((counter < numberOfElements) &&(std::cin >> num) )
    {
        array[counter] = num;
        ++counter;
    }

    //sort the array
    BubbleSort(array);

    std::cout << "Sorted array is as\n";
    PrintArray(array);

    return 0;
}
```

But, I would recomend to use modenr C++ elements, like algorithms to solve the problem.

See:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    size_t numberOfElements{ 0 };
    std::vector<int> array{};

    std::cout << "Enter the number of data to sort: ";
    std::cin >> numberOfElements;
    std::cout << "\nEnter " << numberOfElements << " data values:\n";

    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), numberOfElements, std::back_inserter(array));
    std::sort(array.begin(), array.end());

    std::cout << "\n\nSorted data:\n\n";
    std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```